# Visual Studio Github error

Tags: github, visual-studio-2017

I can't sync push or pull to my remote repository from VS2017. I am getting this error:

```
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a 
fatal error. HttpRequestException encountered.
An error occurred while sending the request.
cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Pushing to https://github.com/cabbytech/CabbyTechDesktop.git
```

I am not sure how to re-enter my credentails for Github in visual studio. This is the first time I have experienced this error and have synced many times on my current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem I opened the Visual Studio Installer and selected to update my Visual Studio 2017 Community installation.

After the installation finished I started Visual Studio and opened the Team Explorer tab, selected Manage Connections and signed into Github again.

After doing that everything worked again (like clone, sync, commit etc..).